# UIViewController's view background color is not changed

Tags: ios, swift3, background-color, presentviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that only shows a `UIView` at the bottom with a fixed height:

```
fileprivate lazy var box: UIView = {
    let box = UIView()
    box.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return box
}()
```

And I'd like to set a clear color to the rest of the view (`self.view`). I'm presenting the view controller from a navigation controller. I'm trying this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    view.isOpaque = false

    configView()
    configConstraints()
}
```

The subview is displayed in blue but the rest of the view is opaque white, I need it to be transparent to see the previous viewController's view.

What can I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

To have transparent Model view controller background you have to set `UIViewController` `providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle` and `definesPresentationContext` properties while presenting the view controller.

**Example**

```
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_ID") {
    vc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    vc.definesPresentationContext = true
    vc.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```